# How to Format a dynamically generated cell

Tags: java, excel, reporting, jxls

Am trying to generate a dynamic excel report using jXLS library.
Below is the jXLS template I am using as input.

```
|<jx:forEach items="${headers1}" var="header">   | ${header.headerText} | </jx:forEach>|
|<jx:forEach items="${rows1}" var="rowItem">     |                      |              |
|<jx:forEach items="${rowItem.columns}" var="cell">|    ${cell.value}   |</jx:forEach> |
|</jx:forEach>                                   |                      |              |
```

With this, I am able to generate excel report with as many as columns returned by the query result set and values. But the problem I am facing is how to format the cells if the column is a date column. I cannot apply the format in jXLS template as its single cell representing all the cells in the report. Here is the definition of Cell.java

```
public class Cell {

    public Cell(Object value) {
        super();
        this.value = value;
    }

    private Object value;

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }


}
```

How can I apply formatting to the cells dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

JXLS just uses the formatting which you provided in your template. For dynamic data they now have this very convenient [grid command](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/reference/grid_command.html), which has the attribute `formatCells`. It takes the format from the specified cell and applies it to the specified data type.

The example use can be found [here](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/samples/dynamic_grid.html) and the example misuse [here](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls/issues/95/formatcells-doesnt-work-in-dynamic-grid).